# Just changed a view layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Before I changed a view layout, Rails show my login view properly. 
But after the change, I have got an error message below.

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Before the change,
"app/views/layouts/application.html.erb"were applied to my login view.

and I wanted to change layout only on my login view.
So, "I made app/views/layouts/login.html.erb" and put some code on the controller.
 def login
    render :layout => 'login'
 end

I guess the error must come from the code,which includes @member.

{:action => 'login'}) do |f| %>

But I don't understand why. Could you give me some advise?

☆members controller

```
def login
    render :layout =>'login'
    @msg = "get"
    @member = Member.new

if request.post? then
  @member = Member.new(params[:member])
  record = Member.find_by_user(params[:member][:user])
  if record == nil then
    @msg = "record is nil."
    @member.errors.add('user',"not registrated!")
  else
    if record.pass != params[:member][:pass] then
      @msg = "password is wrong."
      @member.errors.add('pass','password is wrong!')
    else 
      @msg = "good!"
      @member = record
      session[:login] = record
      redirect_to '/members/' + record.id.to_s
    end
  end
end
```

end

☆layouts/login.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>XXXX</title>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <%= render 'layouts/exheader'%> 
<div class= "container">
 <%= yield %>
</div>
<div class="container">
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

☆login.html.erb(members)

```
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="login_form">
            <h4>Login</h4>
            <%= form_for(@member, :url => {:action => 'login'}) do |f| %>
                <% if @member.errors.any? %>
                    <div id="error_explanation">
                        <h2><%= pluralize(@member.errors.count, "error")%>
                        prohibited this member from being saved:</h2>
                        <ul>
                            <% @member.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                            <li><%=msg %></li>
                            <% end %><%# do |msg|%>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                <% end %><%#  if%>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :user %>
                    <%= f.text_field :user %>
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <%= f.label :pass %>
                    <%= f.password_field :pass %>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <%= f.submit :value => "login" %>
                </div>
            <% end %><%# do |f|%>
        </div><!-- login form -->   
    </div><!--span4 for login -->
```

Comment: At which line does the error occur?

Comment: This line.
<%= form_for(@member, :url => {:action => 'login'}) do |f| %>
     <%# if @member.errors.any? %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will immediately start rendering the view when a `render` occurs. So in your code, you have placed `render :layout => 'login'` at the very beginning of the action, and consequently the view was rendered before executing any action code; thus, all instance variables like `@member` and `@msg` haven't yet been declared, their values are `nil` while rendering the views. So

```
<%= form_for(@member, :url => {:action => 'login'}) do |f| %>
  <%# if @member.errors.any? %>
```

Complains that `@member`, which is a `nil`, has no method `model_name`.

Ultimately you should only place `render` at the end of your controller code. Maybe like this:

```
def login
  @msg = "get"
  @member = Member.new

  if request.post?
    @member = Member.new(params[:member])
    record = Member.find_by_user(params[:member][:user])
    if record.nil?
      @msg = "record is nil."
      @member.errors.add('user',"not registrated!")
    else
      if record.pass != params[:member][:pass]
        @msg = "password is wrong."
        @member.errors.add('pass','password is wrong!')
      else
        @msg = "good!"
        @member = record
        session[:login] = record
        redirect_to '/members/' + record.id.to_s
        return
      end
    end
  end
  render :layout =>'login'
end
```

Comment: Mr. Tamer Shlash, thank you very much. Now I understand the situation.But when I place render at the end of my controller code and try to login, Rails complains Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Comment: @KuniharuAramaki I edited the answer, you may want to check it out now.